# Nullstellensatz to prove Noether Normalization

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

In many commutative algebra texts, Noether Normalization Lemma is proved and then Hilbert's Nullstellensatz is obtained as a corollary.

Nullstellensatz and Normalization Lemma seem to be non-trivial theorems in their own right.   So, can we prove Noether Normalization Lemma after assuming Hilbert's Nullstellensatz.

Comment: I think you want to ask whether one can show that Nulstellensatz implies Noether Normalization. Am I right?

Comment: Ya, that's what I want

Comment: Notice that Noether Normalization works over any field, while Nullstellensatz needs an algebraically closed field.